# TypeScript Error: Property '0' is missing in type

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, observable

I have my interface like this

```js
export interface Details {
  Name: [{
    First: string;
    Last: string;
  }];
}
```

I have an observable config variable:

`Configuration: KnockoutObservable<Details> = ko.observable<Details>();`

and I would like to assign it a value in the constructor as follows:

```js
config = {
  Name: [{
    First: "ABC",
    Last: "DEF"
  },
  {
    First: "LMN",
    Last: "XYZ"
  }]
};

this.Configuration(config);
```

and I am getting an error:

```
Types of property 'Name' is incompatible and property '0' is missing in type.
Type '{ First:string; Last:string; }[]' is not assignable to 
type '[{ First: string; Last:string; }]'
```

I don't have control on changing the interface as it is being used elsewhere.
 What is the correct way to initialize this config variable ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 86):

I came across the same issue and got around it by changing the interface to:

```
    interface Details {
        Name: {
            First: string;
            Last: string;
        }[];
    }
```

I know you may not want the interface changed but hope this helps for anyone that is in this situation.

Comment: I want to kiss you!  I fought this for so long without any answers.  Thanks you so much!

Comment: Ha! I am glad this helped because I definitely found myself in the same boat some time ago.

Comment: Just in case it isn't obvious the solution here is to move the `[]` to immediately follow `{}` instead of being `[ { } ]`. This is a change in syntax with recent typescript version.

Comment: Thanks a lot : )

Comment: No problem! Glad to see this is still helping people years down the line!

Answer (score 68):

This error can come from incorrectly typing an array (like I just did):

```
myArray:[]; //Incorrect, results in error message of `Property '0' is missing in type`

myArray: Array<string>; //Correct

myArray: string[]; //Also correct
```

The reason is that brackets denote a tuple in Typescript, not an array.

[The Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: brackets? braces? what you mention for me are brackets [] braces are for me{} at best the terms are overloaded. And honestly, why the heck would TS use [] to denote a tuple? that's just wayyyy beyond me.

Answer (score 16):

In this type definition:

```
interface Details {
  Name: [{
    First: string;
    Last: string;
  }];
}
```

`Name` is not an array at compile-time. It's a tuple with one element. Tuples in Typescript are allowed to have extra elements, but they can't have missing elements. As a 1-tuple, `Name` is essentially an array which must have *at least* one element.

However, in this value:

```
const config = {
  Name: [{
    First: "ABC",
    Last: "DEF"
  },
  {
    First: "LMN",
    Last: "XYZ"
  }]
};
```

Since there is no explicit typing, the `Name` property here defaults to array type. Arrays can have any number of elements, including zero - which doesn't fit in a 1-tuple. Hence your error.

Your error can be fixed by giving the compiler a hint that your literal is actually a tuple:

```
const config: Details = { Name: [{...}, {...}] };
```

If you do need to be able to take in an array of names, you'll have to do some casting, maybe something like this:

```
if (names.length > 0) {
  const config = {
    Name: names as Details['Name']
  };
  Configuration(config);
}
```

(You could remove the if check if you can determine that the tuple was simply a mistake by whoever wrote the typings.)

Tuples reference:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: great answer! just helped me out.

Answer (score 11):

Updating the interface to following should fix the issue :

```
 interface Details {
        Name: Array<{
            First: string;
            Last: string;
        }>;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue please?

Comment: I believe, [] in typescript refers to tuple type , Array<> is a closer representation of javascript arrays. That's my understanding .